# Desktop and mobile game in Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, deployment, desktop-application

My question is: it is possible to make in Unity a desktop windows GUI than can control the objects in a mobile game, but in real time. I am new in games development, but if it is possible can you help answering this question?

Thank you,

Comment: Keyword is Unity remote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick Google search "unity use phone as controller" turns up [this](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/easy-wifi-controller-turn-your-mobile-phone-into-a-controller.308553/), and plenty of other results. I'm sure it's possible but I can't help you beyond that.

Comment: Thank you very much, however, I was searching unity use computer as controller in phone. But,  I need to make more research. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you is 'new' then I advise for you to start for steps. **First** step - Try create a simple game like (cube jump). **Second** step, search for libraries that allow some connection by wifi with unity. I see a lot libraries for VR in assets shop unity.
But if your really is new, this can be hardest.

Comment: Thank you a lot. :)